# Error inflating class <unknown> with my own class

Tags: android, syn

I want to load recyclerView in UITask.java.

I try to get the recyclerView's ID through View

**UITask.java**

```
 protected void onProgressUpdate(List... values) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(BaseApplication.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_main,null);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    StaggeredGridLayoutManager layoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3,StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    adapter = new photoAdapter(photosList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

But it catches error:

**android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class**

```
RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
Process: com.yaminet.materialtest, PID: 22856
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file               line #9: Error inflating class <unknown>
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error  inflating class <unknown>
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_margin="16dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header">

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**build.grade**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.yaminet.materialtest"
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

How do I get RecyclerView's ID in non MainActivity?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: But problem is in XML layout inside of java code

Comment: I check my XML layout,It works.

Comment: Post the code of your `activity_main.xml` and the constructor of your custom view(if you have used in line 9 of your layout file).

Comment: Issue is in 9th line of your xml. ctrl + G and type 9 to go to that line.

Comment: The 9th line is:"    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout",but it can works.

Comment: and I have posted my code in the question.

Comment: Share your build.gradle under app folder

Comment: I have posted bulid.grade in the question.

Comment: I wonder when is `onProgressUpdate()` being called and why do you inflate the layout there? Maybe you should either make a reference to you activity/fragment in `UITask` or setting up callback interface.

Comment: UITask extends AsyncTask,I want to load the RecyclerView data in the new thread.I need to get the recyclerView id if I want to change it.